# Determinant of a character

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

let two characters $\chi$ and $\vartheta$ of a finite group $G$ (assumed to be non-null). 
Let $\mathfrak{X}$ and $\mathfrak{Y}$ be representations of $G$ affording respectively $\chi$ and $\vartheta$ . Then the character $\chi+\vartheta$ is afforded by the representation $\begin{bmatrix} \mathfrak{X}&0 \\ 0&\mathfrak{Y}\end{bmatrix}$. From there I deduce $det(\chi+\vartheta)=det(\chi)det(\vartheta)$. Is that correct ? I am asking because it is a result I never see presented nor used in textbooks.

Addendum: I found some very nice material in the chapter 30 of Karpilovski (including the formula above): Group Representations Volume 1.

Comment: please, what is the matrix of a representation that you have writed?

Comment: do you mean $\det(\begin{bmatrix} \mathfrak{X}&0 \\ 0&\mathfrak{Y}\end{bmatrix}) = \det(\mathfrak{X})\det(\mathfrak{Y})$ ? and since $\begin{bmatrix} \mathfrak{X}&0 \\ 0&\mathfrak{Y}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathfrak{X}&0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0&0 \\ 0&\mathfrak{Y}\end{bmatrix}$. $\ \ $  but $\begin{bmatrix} \mathfrak{X}&0 \\ 0&\mathfrak{Y}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathfrak{X}&0 \\ 0&I\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} I&0 \\ 0&\mathfrak{Y}\end{bmatrix}$ seems more appropriate for understanding $\det(\chi) \det(\vartheta)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, my proof is: $det(\chi+\vartheta)(g)=det \begin{bmatrix} \mathfrak{X}(g) & 0\\ 0& \mathfrak{Y}(g) \end{bmatrix}=det\mathfrak{X}(g)det\mathfrak{Y}(g)=det\chi(g)det\vartheta(g)$

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is $\det \chi(g)$. I just saw (for an irreducible representation) $\det \mathfrak{X}(g)$ depends only on $tr(\mathfrak{X}(g)) = \chi(g)$, is it what you mean ?

Comment: The character $det\chi$ is defined for every $g\in G$ by $det\chi(g)=\det\mathfrak{X}(g)$ where $\mathfrak{X}$ is a representation affording $\chi$.

Comment: Looks correct. But the determinant may be pretty boring as a function. It is a 1-d character of $G$ no matter what $\chi$ you use. So it will be constant $1$ on the commutator subgroup and a root of unity elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki. It gives some nice formulas though like the following one: let $\rho_G$ be the regular character of $G$. Then $det\rho_G=\prod_{\chi\in Irr(G)}(det\chi)^{\chi(1)}$ :-).

Comment: Don't you also get
$$\det \rho_G(x)=(-1)^{|G|-|G|/ord(x)}$$ for all elements $x\in G$?

Comment: How do you prove it?

Comment: Multiplication by $x$ moves the elements of $G$ in $|G|/ ord(x)$ cycles of length $ord(x)$. Each orbit produces a matrix block of determinant $(-1)^{ord(x)-1}$ (odd length cycles are even permutations and even length cycles are odd permutations).

Comment: I think that the matrix of the regular representation of $g$ is the permutation matrix of the permutation associated to $g$ by the Cayley homomorphism $\gamma:G\hookrightarrow \mathfrak{S}_G$. Hence $det\rho_G(g)=\varepsilon(\gamma(g))$. If you take $G=\mathfrak{S}_5$ and $g=(12)$, then $\varepsilon(g)=-1$ yet $(-1)^{120-120/2}=1$. Is my reasoning wrong ?

Comment: @Jyrki The determinant of characters show up various places. For example there are several results along the lines of "this character lifts iff its determinant does".

Comment: Nicolas, the Cayley representation of $(12)\in \mathfrak{S}_5$ is the product of 60 disjoint 2-cycles. The orbits are of the form $\{g,(12)g\}$ with $g$ ranging over a set of representative of cosets of $\langle (12)\rangle\le \mathfrak{S}_5$. In other words $\mathfrak{S}_G\simeq\mathfrak{S}_{120}$ in your example.

Comment: True Jyrki. Thanks.